# How to name a database of a Rails app with a multi-word name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

If a Rails app is called `Foo`, then the related databases are called:

```
foo_development
foo_test
foo_production
```

However, if an app is called something like `MgFoo` / `mg_foo`, then how should the databases be called: `mgfoo_development` or `mg_foo_development` or some other way?

Comment: Go to terminal. Type `rails new MgFoo`. Open database.yml and check the database name.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
database: <%= Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore %>
```

or

```
database: <%= "#{Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore}_development" %>
```